# How does a Blazor app work after publishing?

Tags: blazor

I've created a simple Blazor WebAssembly application. Everything is fine, but I can't understand how it really works. I published and launched it. What I see in the network tab in the browser is 3 requests:

1. `blazor.webassembly.js` - I guess this is the file containing the code responsible for bootstraping the whole application
2. `blazor.boot.json` - this file contains information about all the assemblies and the entry point
3. `dotnet.6.0.10.fuzsuyypq1.js` - this seems like a file containing the application code. In the network tab, I see that the AJAX requests that my app makes are initiated in this file. However, when I go to that file, I see only just some JavaScript code and a signature block. I don't know what that block means. When I search for some code that I have in my app, I can't find anything. Also, this file is like 56 kB, so it's quite small.

Could you tell me where the application code is located?

Comment: blazor.boot.json tells Blazor which "application files" to fetch to use in the browser. The files get placed in net7.0/publish/wwwroot/_framework/. In there you can see files like dotnet.wasm, System.Linq.dll and any other assemblies used.

Comment: Yeah, but it seems they aren't downloaded. At least I don't see them in the network tab.

Comment: Assemblies are cached in the browser by default, they will only download the first time you visit the site, unless you clear your cache. For chrome you can go into application -> storage and click "clear site data" to see the download again

Comment: Oh, you're right. The assemblies were indeed in cache. Thanks!